# heap VS anon memory in the result of pmap

Tags: heap-memory, solaris

The following is the result after run on solaris, it shows there are two heaps, but in my understanding, for a process, there is only one heap which is a large continuous memory which can be managed by brk to expand or shrink the size. And for anon memory, a process can have many anon memory which can be managed by mmap/munmap. Is my understanding correct? or I read the result of the pmap wrongly?

sol9# pmap -sx `pgrep testprog`

...
00022000    3960    3960    3960       -   8K rwx--     **[ heap ]**

00400000  131072  131072  131072       -   4M rwx--     **[ heap ]**

...
FF390000       8       8       -       -   8K r-x--  libc_psr.so.1

FF3B0000       8       8       8       -   8K rwx--    **[ anon ]**

...

---

total Kb  135968  135944  135112       -

Answer (score 5):

You are both correct and misreading the pmap output.   If you had done `pmap -x` the results would probably be less confusing, showing the heap just once, but since you added the `-s` flag, it breaks down the heap into segments with different page mappings.

The addresses starting at 0x0022000 are not aligned properly to be mapped to a 4Mb page, so they use 3960kb of 8k pages.   0x0022000+(3960*1024) = 0x00400000

At 0x00400000 the address is properly aligned for 4Mb pages, so the heap switches to using the larger pages with fewer page table entries.

If you wanted to ensure that your heap started at the proper alignment to use 4Mb pages for the whole thing instead of starting with 8k until it reached an alignment boundary, then you would link your program with [`-M /usr/lib/ld/map.bssalign`](https://hg.java.net/hg/solaris~on-src/file/tip/usr/src/common/mapfiles/common/map.bssalign#l22) to do that.

A slightly more in-depth explanation can be found in the [Page Size and Memory Layout blog post](http://blogs.oracle.com/d/entry/page_size_and_memory_layout) from [*Solaris Application Programming*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0138134553) author [Darryl Gove](http://blogs.oracle.com/d/).